# Getting rid of spurious colors during color detection in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I'm using the following code for detecting all the colors in a figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np


# Plot the rectangle:

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7), facecolor='white')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax.add_patch(Rectangle((0.5, 0.5), 0.1, 0.1, fc=[1,0,0], ec='none'))
ax.axis([0, 1, 0, 1])
ax.axis('off')
fig.canvas.draw()


# Save data in a rgb string and convert to numpy array:

rgb_data = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8, sep='')
rgb_data = rgb_data.reshape((int(len(rgb_data)/3), 3))


# Print only unique colors:

rgb_data = np.vstack(set(tuple(row) for row in rgb_data))
print rgb_data


# Show the figure:

plt.show()
```

In this example, I'm plotting a red rectangle on a white background, and the code returns the colors `[255 0 0]` (red) and `[255 255 255]` (white). The code works very well as long as the edgecolor `ec` is set to `'none'`. On the contrary, when I set `ec='black'` the code returns some spurious colors such as `[247 247 247]`, `[8 6 6]`, etc. Since I want to plot the rectangle WITH its edge AND to detect ONLY its color (plus the background color), my solution was:

1. plot it once without the edge
2. detect its color
3. erase the figure
4. plot it again with the edge

This solution works but is not very elegant. Moreover, it becomes too slow when I have to plot several rectangles in the same figure.

Do you know if there is any alternative solution that allows me to plot the rectangle only once?

**EDIT**

**IMPORTANT:** I forgot to say that when I have several rectangles, they may be overlapping. In this case I would like to find the colors of the visible rectangles only. That's why I'm using the code above.

Comment: I suspect what is happening here is some interpolation that is used to draw the canvas to achieve smoothing effects. This will probably result in your unexpected colors.

Comment: To find out the colors of the patches, you can use `print [p.get_facecolor() for p in ax.patches]`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest many thanks for your suggestion. Actually it works, but I have to apologize because I forgot to say that when rectangles are overlapping, I would like to find the colors of the visible rectangles only. I think the solution you propose finds the colors also of the hidden rectangles. I have edited my question to clarify this point.